# How many hands can we make from a deck? (pg-75, generating functionology)

Tags: generating-functions

> Given an exponential family $\mathbb{F}$. For each $n \geq 0 $, and $ k \geq 1$, let $h(n,k)$ denote the numebr of hands $H$ of weight $n$ that consist of $k$ cards, and are such that each card in the hand is a relabeling of some card in some deck in $\mathbb{F}$. **Repetitions are allowed, that is we are permitted to take several copies of the same card from one deck and to relabel those copies with different label sets.**
>
> How can we expression $h(n,k)$ in terms of $d_1,d_2..,,$ where $d_i$ is the number of different cards in deck $D_i$ ($ i\geq 1)$

I'm trying to make sure I understood this definition correctly, suppose I have an exponential family with one deck:

[image]

Then, if I were to calculate $h(2,2)$ would the answer be $4$? I think these would be the selections:

[image]

I had much earlier asked a question on Hand, Deck and expt family [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3974142/how-to-intuitively-understand-the-concept-of-hand-deck-card-and-exponential-f)